# How to git reset --hard everything but 4 files

Tags: git

Assuming nothing is staged, what's the recommended way to reset all the work you've done, except for files:

```
app/models/a.rb
app/views/a/index.html.rb
config/foo.rb
config/bar.rb
```

Other dirty files exist in app/models/ and app/views/ that I don't want to keep.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As you described the problem, it doesn't look like you want do `reset`. The simplest thing for this is:

```
git add app/models/a.rb app/views/a/index.html.rb config/foo.rb config/bar.rb
git checkout .
```

so, it adds your 4 files into the index, and checks out clean versions (i.e. discards changes) for other files.

I assume you have not staged (`git add`) modified files before (you should then unstage it using reset).

Comment: I think I prefer this w/ `git clean -fd`

Comment: Yes, it's different - `checkout` works with tracked files, `clean` with untracked.

Comment: nice one, made my day :)

Comment: A short explanation on *why* this works would be interesting!

Comment: @np8 `git add` adds files to staged, then `git checkout .` works on unstaged files

Answer (score 16):

One way is to git commit those four files, then reset hard, and then undo the commit:

```
git add <files to keep>
git commit -m "temp"
git reset --hard
git reset HEAD~
```

Answer (score 7):

If those four files are in the index while the dirty files aren't, a simple [`git-clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) should do the trick. If unsure, use the `--dry-run` switch first, and notice the `--exclude` switch.

Otherwise, stick with [siride's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092767/321973)